# Can i remove the "default.aspx" from the url?

Tags: c#, default

When i try remove www from url:

`www.jeans.com.vn`

the result is: `jeans.com.vn/default.aspx`.

I don't want the `/defaul.aspx` too.

How can i remove it?

My code:

```
if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
    builder.Host = Request.Url.Host.Replace("www.", "");
    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Just set [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.path.aspx) to empty or "/":

```
builder.Path = "/";
```