# How to cut "/Default.aspx" from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-routing

Routes are working, but when i start my site up i get

```
 localhost:57564/Default.aspx
```

Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: You can use rewrite rules to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i remove the "default.aspx" from the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699467/can-i-remove-the-default-aspx-from-the-url)

Comment: This really has been asked thousands of times all over the web. Did you really care to search for a minute? People are lazier by the day...

Comment: That wont work, as my site is not online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rewrite rule in your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <rewrite> 
    <rules>   
    <rule name="Default Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Default\.aspx$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is gave me a erorr message.

Comment: Do you have rewrite rule installed in IIS server ? Use this link to download url - rewrite https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: That i'm not sure on.

Comment: added the extension, didn't change anything.

Comment: The configuration section 'rule' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.

Comment: You need to mention the rule in `<rewrite>` block. updated my answer

Comment: try now. added configuration block and system.webserver block